# make alias for program in another directory open file in current direcory

Tags: bash, alias

so my eclipse ide isn't known to bash but located in 
/home/georg/Desktop/eclipse

If I want to open a .c file in say
/home/georg/Desktop/myprograms/helloworld.c

how can i write the alias, ie.
alias=myeclipse'/home/georg/Desktop/eclipse /home/georg/Desktop/myprograms/helloworld.c
'

doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're not using the correct syntax for the `alias` command. Try this instead:

```
alias myeclipse='/home/georg/Desktop/eclipse /home/georg/Desktop/myprograms/helloworld.c'
```

There are other ways to solve this as well. It would be simplest to add `/home/georg/Desktop/eclipse` to your `PATH`, so that bash can find it:

```
export PATH="/home/georg/Desktop/eclipse:$PATH"
```